# Algorithms for distributing natural numbers in to equal piles

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm looking for an algorithm that can take in a set of natural numbers, for example:

```
S = {1, 3, 4, 2, 9, 34, 432, 43}
```

Then divide them into as equal piles as possible. The number of piles are predefined as n.

The goal is to have the sum of the difference between each pile and the lowest pile, to be the smallest.

Here comes an example.

Let's say you have:

```
S = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 }
n = 3
```

Then a solution could be

```
N1 = { 1, 2 }
N2 = { 2, 3 }
N3 = { 1, 2, 3 }
```

The sum of these piles would be 3, 5 and 6. The error would be: (5 - 3) + (6 - 3) = 5.

The algorithm needs to find the solution with the lowest error.

Any help is appreciated. Please comment if something is unclear.

Comment: I have been thinking about some sort of trading, where you trade between the piles, but i dont know when the piles are optimised

Comment: Are you not allowed to redistribute the numbers such as N1 = {1,3} N2 = {1,3} N3 = {1,2,2} ?

Comment: Yes you are, it was just chance :)

Comment: I am sad that nobody pointed out that you can use dynamic programming to solve this in `O(N^2 m)` time and space where `N` is the sum of the sizes of the piles and `m` is the number of elements.  This makes it pseudopolynomial but tractable for many cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that there is no efficient way to solve this problem because it is a NP-hard problem.

Proof:

Let's denote the problem you proposed as P*,

We can reduce the partition problem(known NP-hard) into P* by doing the following
Given a arbitrary partition problem P1, we ask the black box which solve P* to solve P1 with N=2(i.e, divide the set into 2 pile that minimize the different).

If the difference return by the black box is zero, -> there is a solution for P1

If the difference return by the black box is non-zero, -> there isn't a solution for P1

Therefore, P* is NP-hard

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a variation of the https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem. However, the size of the bins is not given thus it is at least as hard as Bin Packing. Thus the problem is NP-hard.

For an approximate solution you could for example calculate the average bin size and perform an adaptation of first-fit or best-fit in order to allow small overpacking.